# QlikSense if statement with muliselect filter

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I have created in QS this multiselect filter which has 7 options that are related to other 7  tables that are linked to the data model.

In my BI tool I do have a map, which has then all of the tables as a separate layer.

What I want to do, is to create a multi-selection filter where the user can select what data to present and lay over the map.

The multi-selection filter looks the following:

```
ShowItem:
LOAD * INLINE [
    ID, Category
    1, Population
    2, Sales
    3, AAA
    4, BBB
    5, CCC
    6, DDD
    7, EEE
];
```

In the dimension definition, I then want to put this kind of formula:

```
=IF(ShowItem.ID = 2, GeoMakePoint(lat,lng), null)
```

It works perfectly **when I have only one selection in the filter**, but once I select 2 AND 6 at the same time, it does not work anymore. In extreme cases, all of the seven layers should be able to overlay.

Any suggestions how to overcome this issue?
Thank you very much for your help!